# Hyperledger Composer Error Identity has not been registered once issued

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been following this [Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html) and I am able to complete it. I issue a new identity, to an existing participant and I create a business card for this identity with the following command:

`composer identity issue --card admin@tutorial-network -f usr001@tutorial-network.card -u usr001 -a "resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#usr001" -x true`

Then, I import that business card via `POST /wallet/import` and I am able to call different REST API operations. After that, I stop the composer-rest-server and after a few minutes I start the composer-rest-server again with the command `composer-rest-server -c admin@tutorial-network -m true -a true`

Then, I authenticate to the REST API using the configured authentication mechanism (in this case passport-github strategy) and if I try to call one operation fro REST API it throws a `A business network card has not been specified` error message, then I import the previous business card via `POST /wallet/import` getting a `no content` which is supposed to be correct.

Finally, when I try to call another REST API operation I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "Error",
"message": "Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: usr001)",
"stack": "Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: usr001)\n    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/username/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:679:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

This is the main issue, I don't know why my identity is not being recongized by the REST API if I used it previously to call some operations.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is one of persistence as captured here ->  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html and the link for persisting identities (ie instructions) is captured here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

All user information is persisted in a LoopBack data source by using a LoopBack connector. By default, the REST server uses the LoopBack "memory" connector to persist user information, which is lost when the REST server is terminated. The REST server should be configured with a LoopBack connector that stores data in a highly available data source, for example a database.