# A business network card has not been specified

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been developing a Hyperledger Composer Chaincode. One of the feature that I need to develop is the enabling of multi user and authentication of the composer rest server. I created a participant thru command line same as the sample code below:

```
composer identity issue --card admin@tutorial-network -f usr001@tutorial-network.card -u usr001 -a "resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#usr001" -x true
```

The output of that line is a .card file for the identity. And then I successfullt imported the wallet card by calling POST request to api/wallet/import. However upon authentication of the user I created the response that I get is below:

```
{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"A business network card has not been specified","stack":"Error: A business network card has not been specified\
```

I found this post from stack overflow and it says that it only happens when the composer don't have the persistent datasource:
[Hyperledger Composer Error Identity has not been registered once issued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319461/hyperledger-composer-error-identity-has-not-been-registered-once-issued)

In our case we are using the cloudant as our database, so I don't know what I am doing wrong in my side. below is my configuration for COMPOSER_DATASOURCES:

```
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "cloudant",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "host": "myhost",
    "port": 443,
    "url": "myurl",
    "database": "composer-wallets"
  }
}'
```

Comment: Did you install the right loopback connector?
Maybe this one could work (I didn't try).
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-cloudant

Comment: Hi Leonardo, actually we are already using the loopback-connector-cloudant in the project as stated in the connector property in above configuration.

Comment: Did you also installed the connector 
`npm install loopback-connector-cloudant --save`?

Comment: Yes, that is included in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the card into the wallet?

```
composer card import -f <The card file name>
```

See for details https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are using broken version of composer-rest-server. I had the same issue with 20.2, when upgraded it to 20.7 - works as expected